# Why is the function in the appdelegate not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to add the current user to the installation class, but for some reason the function is not being called. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this? Below is both the finishlaunchingwithoptions and didregisterfornotifications.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.setApplicationId("***********************",
        clientKey: "****************************")




    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let notificationDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
            self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notificationDictionary)
        }
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            print("saved installation")
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    })


}
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("Couldn't register: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Did you register for remote notifications? :)

Comment: How would I do that? In my settings under my app, notifications are enabled

Comment: You need to have called `UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()` and may also have called `UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings()` too.

Comment: @TwoStraws I updated my code to include the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Thank you. For the avoidance of doubt, would you also please add `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` to your app delegate? It's possible you're being given an error message by iOS that you're not seeing.

Comment: Never call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` yourself. It's called by the application.

Comment: @vadian should I take that line of code out?

Comment: @TwoStraws http://puu.sh/lZdhO/a6f1e7d26f.png

Comment: Yes, you have to. Implement `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:completionHandler` on the same level as the other delegate methods to process the notification when one comes in.

Comment: putting `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)` into the did-finish-launch method definitely deserves a downvote without further reading.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in this situation is that you're running in the iOS Simulator, which does not support remote notifications. So, your `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` will never be called, because you're in the simulator. Try on a device and I suspect it will work first time.

For future readers who find this and have a similar problem, the best way to diagnose the problem is to add this to your app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)");
}
```

Comment: This is what is says but why is the number of pushes 0? http://puu.sh/lZfnU/ac14ed9829.png

Comment: That's a separate problem; you'll need to ask someone experienced in that web service.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend accomplishing this using a [cloud code **beforeSave** trigger](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers) on the `Installation` class. It's incredibly simple and more robust than trying to handle it client-side. Here's all you need to get the job done:

```
// Make sure all installations point to the current user
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    if (request.user) {
        request.object.set('user', request.user);
    } else {
        request.object.unset('user');
    }
    response.success();
});
```

Comment: While it definitely doesn't answer the question, this is a much better way of doing what you want to do, @stackerleet